# "This July" vs "This past July"

Tags: phrases, differences

Which of the two forms is correct when referring to July of 2021? What is the contribution of *past*, if any?

Comment: It's ambiguous.

Comment: What are you doing this weekend?

Comment: Generally one can tell what is meant from context.

Answer (score 3):

"This past July" removes the ambiguity which can exist when referring to "This July" and places the reference clearly in the past. It is the opposite of "This coming July" which disambiguates in the opposite direction. "This past July" refers to the most recently passed and "This coming July" refers to the most imminent one.

Normally the context and the tense of an associated verb render the use of either "past" or "coming" unnecessary. For instance "This July we went to Italy" and "This July we are going to Greece." are completely unambiguous since you can't "have gone" in a month that has not yet arrived nor can you be "going" in one that is past (unless you have access to a Tardis or an adapted Delorian).

Answer (score -1):

For starters, when being unambiguous I'd prefer to say "Last July" or "Next July," reserving "This July" for use specifically during the month of July.  So my opinion about the correct form for July 2021 would be "Last July."

But people use "This July" with a much larger and harder-to-pin-down intent than that.

"This July" seems to refer to the most recent, provided that it is very recent, and the next, otherwise. I would expect it to refer to July 2021 if I heard it in July, August or September 2021.  But now it's no longer recent enough to feel like a valid reference to me.  It being now October, I would hear "This July" as meaning July 2022.

"This Past July" would be more correct now, I guess, because July 2021 is no longer recent enough for "This July" to evoke it.

Comment: Where I live, "Last July", spoken during August-December will most often be understood to mean July _last year_, not July _this year_.  And "This July" is generally understood to be in the current year (past or future, depending on the time of speaking).